# How to restart ADB manually from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I previously developped Android apps on Android Studio . Everything works fine.

I work on real device, and Android Studio recognize it without issue.

Suddenly when I exit android studio and  disconnect and reconnect my device, it doesn't recognize my device anymore, I have to exit and restart Android Studio.

I can't find a way to "Reset adb" like Android Studio.

I follow the below instruction(Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration) and enabled ADB,but still below error occurred.

Error:-

[image]

I using windows system.

Any help great appreciation.

Comment: Have you tried killing the process from task manager?

Comment: What does ADB stands for?

Comment: Android Device Bridge

Comment: ADB stands for Android Debug Bridge [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb?hl=es-419) you have a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Open Command prompt and go to

android sdk>platform-tools>

`adb kill-server`

press enter

and again

`adb start-server`

press enter

Comment: I have done the same thing but still issue replicated.

Comment: It's a working solution.If you think it is not working you have to again select your emulator from emulators drop down list because it creates a new instance.

Comment: this can also be done with the terminal within Android studio. Use cd.. and cd sdk, cd platform-tools to get it the right folder.

Comment: You can also done with in Android Studio terminal with your project path only. No need to navigate do sdk/platform-tools path. I checked in the version 3.1.1

Comment: @warlock:  What about Mac os?

Comment: Also `Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb devices`.

Comment: I had `chrome://inspect` open at the time and for whatever reason I had to close that tab before kill/start server would run correctly.

Comment: Command prompt isnt Android Studio this musnt beeen the accepted one, Mia´s is the correct one

Comment: If any of u are unable to make your device appear in android studio, follow this answer. Do it step by step It works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77590348/501439

Answer (score 26):

open command  prompt -> `cd` to your sdk\platform-tools
type below command:

```
adb kill-server && adb start-server
```

Comment: When I type the command above i get a message saying " Error running 'zsh: command not found: adb ': Cannot run program "zsh:" (in directory "/Users/username/AndroidStudioProjects/projectname"): error=2, No such file or directory' "

Answer (score 20):

Most of the answer is for restarting adb server in the command line.

Jiří's answer is the correct answer for this question (to restart adb server IN ANDROID STUDIO), though it's been redesign as shown below.

go to Tools > Troubleshoot Device Connections

ps. you need to hit "Next" two times to find this **Restart ADB server** button.

[image]

[Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2.](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)

Answer (score 14):

open cmd and type the following command

```
netstat -aon|findstr 5037
```

and press enter.

you will get a reply like this :

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3372
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:50126        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:50127        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50127        127.0.0.1:5037         TIME_WAIT       0
```

this shows the pid which is occupying the adb. in this 3372 is the value. it will not be same for anyone. so you need to do this every time you face this problem.

now type this :

```
taskkill /pid 3372(the pid you get in the previous step) /f
```

Voila! now adb runs perfectly.

Comment: Behind corporate port policy expiration and re-gaining port policy again, I had to waste a week figuring out how to make my ADB work. This answer worked for me!

Answer (score 13):

1. Open a Task Manager by pressing CTRL+ALT+DELETE, or right click at the bottom of the start menu and select Start Task Manager. [see how to launch the task manager here](http://www.7tutorials.com/7-ways-launch-task-manager-windows-8)
2. Click on `Processes` or depending on OS, `Details`. Judging by your screenshot it's Processes.
3. Look for adb.exe from that list, click on `END PROCESS`
4. Click on the restart button in that window above. That should do it.

Basically by suddenly removing your device ADB got confused and won't respond while waiting for a device, and Android Studio doesn't want multiple instances of an ADB server running, so you'll have to kill the previous server manually and restart the whole process.

Comment: It will automatically starting adb.exe when i am click the end process

Comment: @User if you reconnect your device then only end process and let adb restart, does it still have the same error?

Comment: yes  same error occurred when i am connect the device also .

Comment: Or just open the Terminal window inside Android Studio and do: taskkill /im adb.exe /f

Answer (score 7):

I do not find a perfect way in Android Studio, get the process id and kill it from terminal:

```
ps -e | grep adb
kill -9 pid_adb
```

Answer (score 4):

Open task manager and kill adb.exe, now adb will start normally

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue just fallowed some min steps in Android studio:

Manually fallowing steps in android studio

1. Goto Command promt and in Command promt fallow a android SDK file path  "android sdk>platform-tools>"  **adb kill-server** press enter
2. **adb start-server** press enter

-------------------------------------------------OR-----------------------------------------------------------------------

1. Open Command promt and got android sdk file path 
         **adb kill-server && adb start-server**

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Android Studio Open Terminal

```
 adb kill-server
```

press enter
and again

```
 adb start-server
```

press enter

Otherwise

Open Command prompt and got android

```
sdk>platform-tools> adb kill-server
```

press enter

and again

```
adb start-server
```

press enter

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio:

Go to: *Tools*  ->  *Android*  ->  *Android Device Monitor*

see the *Device* tab, under many icons, last one is drop-down arrow.

Open it.

At the bottom: *RESET ADB*.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling Android Studio, Is working without adb kill-server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "**USB debugging**" turns on.

I never had this issue with my other devices before. However, today I worked on a device and encountered this issue. Actually took me a while to debug it. Always thought "**USB debugging**" is on automatically when turning on the "**Developer Options**". But turns out its device dependent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Restart adb**

Android Studio uses `Android Debug Bridge (adb)` inside

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

e.g.

```
alex@yoAlex5$ adb kill-server
alex@yoAlex5$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this problem since i have installed another `adb server` for another software.

So if you are a linux user simply open terminal and type:

`killall adb`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem could be the following:

1. Go to **~.android\avd{your_device}.avd**
2. Delete all files with **.lock** extention

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify restart command by creating a file "restartadb.bat" at system32 it should looks like :

@echo off
adb kill-server
adb start-server

then open cmd & run command "restartadb"

Answer (score -1):

When I had this problem, I wrote `adb kill-server` and `adb restart-server` in terminal, but the problem appeared again the next day. Then I updated GPU debugging tools in the Android SDK manager and restarted the computer, which worked for me.