# android studio - work with device monitor emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I am building a simple gps tests with android studio and I want to test it with my PC.

So I ran the code and I want to change the gps coordinates of the device during the runtime. so I open the ANDROID DEVICE MONITOR in android studio, then it pops up a message saying:

> "Following debug sessions will be closed: app"

I press OK in order to activate the android device monitor, and then I want to change the coords in the ANDROID EMULATOR tab, but everything is disabled there and I can't press anything... any ideas?

I know it is related something to the debug mode or something, or ADB, but I don't really know how to start with it.

thank you

- EDIT: HERE IS PICTURE OF WHAT I WANT TO EDIT AND I CAN'T:
  [PICTURE](https://i.imgsafe.org/03738ed817.gif)

Comment: try restarting your Adb

Comment: @MujammilAhamed how do I do that? I am a bit new to the whole debugging world

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29826345/5515371 restaring adb

Comment: @MujammilAhamed it doesn't work still... I added a picture to show what I want to edit and what is disabled in there.

Comment: did you try to run as administrator

Comment: @MujammilAhamed what do you mean? I just hit on the "run" button and that it. then open the device monitor but as you can see all is disabled there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118868/discussion-between-mujammil-ahamed-and-dani-jinji).