# Have to restart Android studio for it to recognise my android device. how to solve it?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Phone gets auto disconnected after 20-30 minutes and the Andriod studio shows they are no connected devices when I click run. I tried re-installing ADB , changed connect as to Camera(PTP), installed universal ADB , nothing worked for me

I have a Xiaomi MI4I device and this is causing a lot of lost time during development.

Comment: why do want to restart android studio?

Comment: what you have tried is not clear. "tried all solutions googled", is not enough for the definition of a good SO question. The faster you update your question the better are your chances to stay on.

Comment: You probably want to restart the adb server

Comment: Phone gets auto disconnected after 20-30 minutes and the Andriod studio shows they are no connected devices when I click run. I tried re-installing ADB , changed connect as to Camera(PTP), installed universal ADB , nothing worked for me

Comment: Restarting the ADB helped. it worked [this is how you can restart your ADB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826101/how-to-restart-adb-manually-from-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Disable and again enable this.