# Visual Studio Xamarin no longer displaying Android Emulators or phones to deploy too

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I am using Xamarin on Visual Studio to create a few different android apps. All of a sudden (after installing drivers for me new phone - OneP;us 5t) my visual studio has stopped allowing me to deploy to a phone or an emulator.

[image]

Before where it says "start" it would be a drop down list of all the devices I want to deploy it to but it won't show them anymore. I haven't changed any settings or altered anything. I also have an AVD created and also an android phone plugged in and it won't recognise either.

[image]

Any idea what could of caused this and how to fix it?

PS, I'm using visual studio 2017.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the adb? (Andriod Debug Bridge)

CHeck this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826101/how-to-restart-adb-manually-from-android-studio

Comment: @maplemale nah that didn't fix anything, thanks though!

Comment: when you select multiple startprojects, the option is gone, but last target is remembered and used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your `Android SDK Tools` to v26+ and create a virtual device using the new tooling.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/

The emulator manager tool that you are using has been deprecated by Google and thus does not appear in Visual Studio.