# ADB Device not found

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools, vuzix

I have a weird problem with my adb. I have a Vuzix M300 and a couple of android phones. The thing is after starting to use my Vuzix M300, my android phones are not being detected by my ADB although my Vuzix is now being detected. This was not the case before using vuzix. Before Vuzix my android phones were being detected normally, now its not being detected and only Vuzix is now being detected. What's the problem here?

Comment: Try restarting the adb server. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29826345/2768706) answer

Comment: already tried it man . No use , because of this adb problem , my unity application is now not able to push apk to my mobile, although it is able to push to vuzix m300 . Dont know why

Comment: Considering you're on Windows, try uninstalling the drivers from device manager or use ADB over Wi-Fi.

Comment: change your cable

Comment: Hrishikesh Kokate tried uninstalling from device manager . I uninstalled ADB Interface and it didnt work .

Comment: @SamSundar Use ADB over Wi-Fi then.

Comment: Hrishikesh Kokate nah man , if i want to install Recovery then i need adb for sure . And also i have to add this . When i connect redmi , its detecting but when i connect oneplus its not detecting .

Comment: @Sam Sundar remove all Android device like drivers from PC and try Google's drivers: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: So solved the problem guys . I have multiple ADB installed and then i selected the adb provided by android studio and it worked. Then i deleted all existing adb from environmental variables and added the android studio ADB and it works now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download ADB Drivers (Universal) from [here](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/), install them, and try again. It should work.

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: Mayur Dabhi oneplus 6t . Redmi is being detected now . But not my oneplus and other usb c devices .

Comment: which window in your PC or Lappy?

Comment: So solved the problem guys . I have multiple ADB installed and then i selected the adb provided by android studio and it worked. Then i deleted all existing adb from environmental variables and added the android studio ADB and it works now .

Answer (score 0):

first be sure the adb installed (depend on your Os)

after that open Android Studio Terminal and Write :

```
adb devices
```

and The outPut should Like This:

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
FA57NY900383    device
```

after That, U can Run On Your RealDevice Phone Or any Device.