# How can I develop my own apps for the Huawei P30 Pro?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I have been developing some apps with Xcode for my iPhone but recently I got the Huawei P30 Pro and would like to start making my own apps for it.
I've tried Android Studio for Mac but it doesn't detect my phone plus google doesn't show any results for developing apps for the Huawei.

Is it possible or is there nothing I can do as of now?

I've enabled USB Debugging on the phone and run 'ads devices' which shows my device as connected but still noting in Android Studio.

Comment: there is no such thing as developing apps for huawei, you develop apps for android.

Comment: Also have more than one `adb-server` doesn't work. So `adb kill-server` from the command line and [restart ADB manually from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29826101/295004)

Comment: Sorry yeah I see what I wrote and what I mean was that I can't build and run a basic app then test it on my phone like I can with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally revoked access to debugging try turning debugging off and back on again you NEED debugging for any form of android development. as for no documentation, that is OK your phone is new and there will not be much info on the specifics, just google stuff about android development in general.

Answer (score 0):

If Android Studio doesn't detect your device, you may want to try using wifi to connect the device, I use AS on a mac every day, and the devices I have often disconnect when cabled, but with this they stay connected for days.

1. Connect device via cable.
2. Open terminal / preferred command line app.
3. Run command `adb devices`. If no device detects unplug and try again, if it continues with no device then check settings on device that usb debugging is enabled, and enabled in charging mode.
4. If device connected:

   - if only one device, run `adb tcpip 5555`
   - if multiple devices run `adb -s deviceid tcpip 5555`
5. If successful then disconnect the device
6. Run command `adb connect 192.168.x.x:5555` with x.x being your device IP address.

If that's all done and it says connected, then you should see it in AS.