# ADB devices offline

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I have Oppo A5S and ı try to debug without usb my devices looks like this not like ip address ı try to connect with ip address but when ı unplugn my cable my devices looks offline how can i fix this ?

[image][image]

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29826345/4788260

Comment: I already try this but when i unpulign my devices its not work again

Comment: check if you have enabled developer option and USB debugging  in that

Comment: they are also open

Comment: check if you have installed the latest Google USB driver in Android SDK and try to restart the system. Is it happening for all devices or the particular one?

Comment: he code in the first photo and the rope in the second photo belong to the same phone also i update all of them

Answer (score 5):

After installing the latest android sdk, you could also try

`adb reconnect offline`

Answer (score 1):

## You could try this:

#### Commands

1. `adb kill-server`
2. `adb start-server`
3. `adb tcpip 1234`
4. `adb connect <ip>:1234`
5. `adb devices`

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to pair your device to the adb client. Newer Android versions need this, here is tutorial at the Lineage wiki:

```
On your device

    Go to the developer settings
    Press Enable Wireless debugging
    Select Pair device with pairing code

You will see a dialog showing you IP address, port and a code.
On your computer

    Open a command line window
    Type adb pair <ip>:<port> and replace <ip> and <port> with the data seen on the device
    You will be asked for the pairing code. Type it in and hit Enter
    You will now see an output similar to Successfully paired to <ip>:<port>
    To connect to the device, type adb connect <ip>:<port> and replace <ip> and <port> with the data seen on the Wireless debugging page after closing the pairing dialog
```

https://wiki.lineageos.org/how-to/adb-over-wifi

Answer (score 0):

in Windows you can kill adb service by `Alt+Ctrl+Delete`, find adb.exe and kill the service. it will refresh current emulators,

adb connect "device ip:5555" to connect to real devices.